# Indoor Map Image loading with Texture2D view Issue in Xamarin.forms and UrhoSharp

Tags: dictionary, xamarin.forms, textures, indoor-positioning-system, urhosharp

I have a issue with UrhoSharp. I want to load a Indoor Map image with 2D texture. I create a scene with Octree(Urho Class)with Box Shape and it's comes in a 3d view.
So, how can I achieve the same in 2D view any suggestion or demo will be so helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use staticsprite2d to load your 2d texture and view from orthographic camera. 
Refer https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Urho.Urho2D.StaticSprite2D/

```
       //Create  sprite image
        var floorNode = _scene.CreateChild();
        floorNode.Position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.0f);
        StaticSprite2D staticSprite = floorNode.CreateComponent<StaticSprite2D>();
        staticSprite.Color = Color.White;
        staticSprite.BlendMode = BlendMode.Alpha;
        var sprite = ResourceCache.GetSprite2D("floorplan_image.jpg");
        staticSprite.Sprite = sprite;

        //Create a camera
        Node cameraNode = _scene.CreateChild("camera");
        var camera = cameraNode.CreateComponent<Camera>();
        camera.Orthographic = true;
        cameraNode.Position = (new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f));
        camera.OrthoSize = (float)Graphics.Height * PixelSize;
```

Comment: Thanks Tobi for your answer.
Actually, I am using material to load the Image.

Comment: Thanks Tobi for your answer.Actually, I am using material to load the Image.

var plane = baseNode.CreateComponent<StaticModel>();
plane.Model = CoreAssets.Models.Plane;
var imageUrl = "here Image url";
var wc = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }; 
var img = new Image(Context) { Name = "MyTextureImage" };
img.Load(new MemoryBuffer(wc.DownloadData(imageUrl)));
plane.SetMaterial(Material.FromImage(img));

Image loading fine with 2D, but moving in a 3D way. So, how can I move the Image in a 2D way also when I zoom the Image it should display in a 3D way like Google Map.

Comment: @PuneetMahali  If you want panning effect like Google Maps, you can move your camera on XY plane. For zoom effect, change your camera zoom value.    https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Urho.Camera.Zoom/

Comment: I already tried to change the camera zoom value but still moving in 3D.

Comment: How can I zoom on X,Y axis also I tried Orthographic but it's stops the movement?